# Numerical method for self-consistency of one-dimensional probability density function

Tags: pr.probability, na.numerical-analysis

I have an integral equation for self-consistency of one-dimensional probability density function, like this

$$\rho_x(x) = \frac{1}{|a|}\int \int \rho_x\left(\frac{s-b}{a}\right) \rho_P(p) \delta(x-g(s,p) ) ds~dp$$

$g$ is  tabulated curve measured experimentally. Moreover $P$ is also random variable. The PDF of $P$, $\rho_P(P)$ was also  measured experimentally. The good news is $P$ and $x$ are independent.

The question is: what is the best numerical method to get $\rho_x(x)$ distribution?

Thank you.

Comment: do you have quick ways of solving $x=g(s,p)$, for a discretization of $s,p$? Also is $\rho_x(x)$ intended?.

Comment: yes, I can solve $x=g(s,p)$ very quick. $\rho_x(x)$ is unknown, I think, it's quite smooth but multimodal PDF.

Comment: @user292689: i'm just confused by the double occurrence of $x$ in $\rho_x(x)$. What kind of boundary conditions do you have?

Comment: I'm still seeing $\rho_x(x)$.

Comment: Yes, It is self-consistency. The idea is that: we looking for distribution $\rho_x(x)$ which projects into itself. The projection or map is $g(x,P)$ which depends upon an other variable (parameter) $P$. $P$ is random variable with distribution $\rho_P(P)$. $P$ is independent.

Comment: double integration accumulates all transaction to point $x$ from all possible $x$ (integral $ds$) and all possible $P$ (integral $dp$)